# R's `parallel::detectCores` to detect physical cores on Linux

Tags: r, parallel-processing

The `detectCores` function in the R `parallel` package has an option of `logical = FALSE` that will return the number of physical cores.

I have a AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor, but on Linux, I get

```r
> detectCores(logical = F)
[1] 16
```

Looking at the help for the `logical` option, it says

> if possible,
> use the number of physical CPUs/cores (if FALSE) or logical CPUs (if
> TRUE). Currently this is honoured only on macOS, Solaris and Windows.

And so, being on Linux, I should not expect this work. I am surprised that it does not work on Linux given that it can work on other *nix systems.

Does anyone know of any function in R that will detect the number of physical cores on a CPU on a Linux based system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parallel::detectCores` calls in case `R.version$os` starts with `linux`

```
system("grep \"^processor\" /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null | wc -l", TRUE)
```

When asking for the lines starting with `core id` the number of physical cores might be detectable with:

```
system("grep \"^core id\" /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null | sort | uniq | wc -l", TRUE)
```

Or accessing `/proc/cpuinfo` direct:

```
sum(!duplicated(grep("^core id", readLines("/proc/cpuinfo"), value = TRUE)))
```

Or maybe also the `physical id` should be considered:

```
nrow(unique(matrix(grep("^core id|^physical id",
 readLines("/proc/cpuinfo"), value = TRUE), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)))
```

Comment: The above worked for me on my Ryzen 7 8-Core Processor, but I also work on a dual Xeon Gold 6154, each of which has 18 cores. The above always give 18, but that's the number of cores on one of the CPUs, not the total number of cores I can use with e.g. `parallel` tools. I am going to conclude then that when working on Linux, you have to read through `/proc/cpuinfo` very carefully to know exactly how many physical cores are available.

Comment: Does the last method using `core id` and `physical id` also return `18` on the Xeon Gold 6154?

Comment: GKi, All your methods lead to 18 on the Xeon, when in fact there 36 cores because there are two cpus, each with 18. Just by luck, `parallell:detectCores` says 36, but that is reading the number of virtual cores on just one cpu.

Comment: [Strange cpuinfo, how many cores does these physical cpu has?](https://superuser.com/a/932418) multiplies `core id` with `physical id`: `sum(!duplicated(grep("^core id", readLines("/proc/cpuinfo"), value = TRUE))) * sum(!duplicated(grep("^physical id", readLines("/proc/cpuinfo"), value = TRUE)))`. Can you share `/proc/cpuinfo` of the Xeon Gold 6154?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
parallelly::availableCores(logical = FALSE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `parallelly::availableCores(logical = FALSE)` still gives me 16. I tried changing the `methods` options from the default `system` but then I just get back `1`. E.g. `parallelly::availableCores(logical = FALSE, methods = 'nproc')` reports `current 1`.